# Vue.js v-bind class width condition

Tags: vue.js

I started working width Vue.js, and I would like to know how I can use conditions width `v-bind`
This is my code (error) :

```html
<input
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  v-bind:class="{'is-invalid': step_1.project_url.error : 'is-valid'}"
  v-model="step_1.project_url.field"
  placeholder="Project url"
>
```

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Read the generated error messages.

Comment: can you help me please by the correct syntax :)

Comment: I think you want `:class="{ 'is-invalid': step_1.project_url.error, 'is-valid': !step_1.project_url.error }"` or perhaps `:class="step_1.project_url.error ? 'is-invalid' : 'is-valid'"`. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.htm

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of binding would be

```
<input
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  v-bind:class="{'is-valid': (step_1.project_url.error !== '' && step_1.project_url.error === true), 'is-invalid': (step_1.project_url.error !== '' && step_1.project_url.error === false)}"
  v-model="step_1.project_url.field"
  placeholder="Project url"
>
```

This will work as per your requirement

Comment: but here I get is-valid by default :( ,   i don't want that

Comment: whats the initial value of 'step_1.project_url.error'?

Comment: ah thats the reason ...so you mean its not a boolean but a string?

Comment: Okay tell me one thing, based on what value you will consider it as a valid?

Comment: valid if its true

Comment: then do one thing...change the data type from string to boolean

Comment: instead of ' ', set the initial value to be false

Comment: already did it same problem, can you write me an example please

Comment: but here one thing is confusing...the attribute name ends with error so when its true it should correspond to 'is-invalid' but what you are saying is it will corresspond to 'valid'

Comment: you have defined the class names in the opposite way

Comment: Based on your definition, I have edited the code pls check it

Comment: can you give me an example please :)

Comment: this time i have is-invalid by default :(

Comment: then what do it want man, either of two classes will be set

Comment: i want to set is-valid or is-invalid / after the form validation  i will update my code now to help :) thanksss

Comment: i followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIG9hRRR6o4&t=208s&ab_channel=LaravelDaily    and i have created is-valid and is-invalid css class to change the input border ( red / gree ) after clicking on next button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228287/discussion-between-amaarrockz-and-alice-munin).

Answer (score -1):

Here you can find a playground that you can mess with and see how things work: https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-bind-styles-lue1g?file=/src/App.vue

For more informations on how to bind classes, you can check the official documentation on the [styling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html).

For reference, here is the kind of line that you wanted to achieve

```html
<input
  type="text"
  :class="[valid === 'okay' ? 'bordered' : '', 'margined']"
  v-model="valid"
/>
```

PS: `:class` is a shorthand for `v-bind:class` !